# NSMutablearray starts printing from last element instead of first

Tags: ios, arrays, for-loop, nsmutablearray, objective-c-blocks

I´m using this method to initialize an nsmutablearray

```
- (void)getAllContacts
{
Contact *contact = [[Contact alloc] init];
self.allContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int i=0;

for (i=0; i<5; i++) 
{
    contact.nome = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Bruno %d", i];    
    [self.allContacts insertObject:contact atIndex:i];
    }
}
```

Pretty straightforward! But right after, i do a for to print it´s elements like:

```
for (int i=0; i<[self.allContacts count]; i++)
{
    Contact *c = [self.allContacts objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"i=%d\nNome:%@", i, c.nome);
}
```

And it will show me 5 times the last element "Bruno 4". It doesn´t start from 0 and increments. What should i do to start from 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  - (void)getAllContacts
    {
    Contact *contact = nil;
    self.allContacts = [NSMutableArray array];

    int i=0;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++) 
    {
        contact = [Contact new];
        contact.nome = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bruno %d", i];    
        [self.allContacts addObject:contact];
        [contact release]
        }
    }
```

and please take a look at: [Memoy Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

Comment: Why should i use self.allContacts = [NSMutableArray array]; instead of init?

Comment: @bruno your "allContacts" Property retain or assign the value?

Comment: i´m using @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *allContacts; but like i´m using an array, maybe i´m doing this wrong.

Comment: ok, so don't care about the memory management that i implement in the above code. The compile takte care of it =)

Comment: Oh, i haven´t even noticed the release. No problem!

Answer (score 3):

Because you are inserting the same object 5 times into the array. You need to create a new `Contact` object at every execution of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is you're actually adding one instance of the Contact class 5 times in the array and only changing `nome` property. Here is the correct way to do this:

```
- (void)getAllContacts
{
     //alloc init returns a retained object and self.allContacts calls the setter, which    additionally retains it.
    self.allContacts = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    int i=0;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++) 
    {
        //Create the Contact object
        Contact *contact = [[Contact alloc] init];
        //Set the nome property
        contact.nome = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bruno %d", i];
        //Add the instance to the array
        [self.allContacts addObject:contact];
        //Release the instance because the array retains it and you're not responsible for its memory management anymore.
        [contact release];
    }
}
```